# Sum of root of difference squared

Tags: python, statistics, metrics, evaluation

I am trying to figure out a formula in a code that I am trying to run. Can you help me to know what they are trying to measure here? it seems a kind of evaluation metric that is similar to Euclidean distance but with minor changes. I searched online but no luck

```
print ("%f"%np.sum(np.sqrt((matrix1-matrix2)**2)))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is computing the sum of the Euclidean distances between all of the items in the matrices/vectors `matrix1` and `matrix2`.

This code is generic code that gets the Euclidean distance between two matrices:

```
np.sqrt((matrix1-matrix2)**2)
```

And then, at the end, the distances are summed up via `np.sum`.

Here is an example which demonstrates how it works:

```
matrix1 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
matrix2 = np.array([2, 4, 6, 8, 10])
subtracted = matrix1-matrix2 # result: [-1 -2 -3 -4 -5]
squared = subtracted**2 # result: [ 1  4  9 16 25]
rooted = squared ** 0.5 # result: [1. 2. 3. 4. 5.]
summed = np.sum(rooted) # result: 15.0
print(summed) # output: 15.0
```

When you are confused by some code and aren't sure what it's doing, it's really helpful to break it up into steps like that, then step through each one in a debugger (or just print the results for each line of code). You can much more easily tell what's going on with code when you play around with it in a test script, generally.

Comment: Thank you so much! that helped me! 
In what situation the summed will be equal to zero? or what does it mean if the final result is zero?

Comment: @saad then the matrices all contain the same point, or maybe even are empty. If they are all the same point, then the distances would be zero and thus the sum would be zero. If there are no points, the sum would be zero because the sum of an empty list is zero. I gave both a try and that definitely held true.